# Match value and count corresponding value differences between two sheets

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets, formula

I have two Google sheets with different `Fictional characters` (column A) and their corresponding `Type` (column B).

**Sheet1**

```
| Fictional character | Type            |
|:--------------------|:---------------:|
| Spider Ham          | Pig             |
| Iron Man            | Human           |
| Captain America     | Human           |
| Thor                | God             |
| Hercules            | God             |
| Superman            | Alien           |
```

**Sheet2**

```
| Fictional character | Type            |
|:--------------------|:---------------:|
| Spider Ham          | Human           |
| Iron Man            | Human           |
| Captain America     | Human           |
| Thor                | God             |
| Hercules            | Demi-God        |
| Doctor Octopus      | Human           |
```

The differences between Sheet1 and Sheet2:

- Sheet1 have the fictional character "Superman", which Sheet2 does not have
- Sheet2 have the fictional character "Doctor Octopus", which Sheet1 does not have
- The fictional character "Spider Ham" and "Hercules" have another type in both sheets

I want to compare how many of the fictional characters that have a different `Type` (excluding characters that does not exist in both sheets)

**Sheet3** should look like this:

```
| Difference          | Sum             |
|:--------------------|----------------:|
| Same type           | 3               |
| Not the same type   | 2               |
```

I have tried with the following, but it's not a valid formula - and I haven't figured out how to exclude if characters that does not exist in both sheets:

`=COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A:A;Sheet1!A:B;2;FALSE)=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A:A;Sheet1!A:B;2;FALSE);"=TRUE")`
`=COUNTIF(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A:A;Sheet1!A:B;2;FALSE)=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A:A;Sheet1!A:B;2;FALSE);"=FALSE")`

Comment: Did you try using a pivot table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same Type:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A7,A11:B16,2,0)=B2:B7,0))
```

Not the same type:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A7,A11:B16,2,0)<>B2:B7,0))
```

Notes:
A2:B7=Sheet 1 data
A11:B16=Sheet 2 data
Change `,` to `;`

Comment: How do I modify `A11:B16` so it work across Sheet1 and Sheet2?

Comment: Thanks - "Same type" is working now:  `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A:A;Sheet2!A:B;2;0)=Sheet1!B:B;0))-1` (added `-1` so I don't have to worry about row length. But "Not the same type" returns 0. I use this `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A:A;Sheet2!A:B;2;0)<>Sheet2!B:B;0))`

Comment: Nevermind my last comment, it worked out perfectly. Thanks you so much!